# BytesIO from url using open()

Tags: python

Can you help me , I need to open `my_url` in `rb` mode. Try to do this.

```
 url = "https://my url/" + file_info.file_path
            response = requests.get(url)

            with open(BytesIO(response.content), "rb") as f:  # Open in 'rb' mode for reading it in way like: 010101010
                byte = f.read(1) 
                #some algorithm..............
                while byte:
                    hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(byte)
                    decimal = int(hexadecimal, 16)
                    binary = bin(decimal)[2:].zfill(8)
                    hiddenData += binary
                byte = f.read(1)
```

Have an error:

> Expected str,bytes or.osPathLIke object, not _ioBytesIO

Can you help ,please, how I should open my url in `"rb"` mode?

I was trying to open an image, using `Pillow` - it is okay. But as for using `open()` , I can not do the same. Please..

Comment: It's not clear why you are putting the response into a BytesIO object. But in any case you need to show the full traceback so that we can tell where the error is occurring.

Comment: you need `f = BytesIO(response.content)` `f` is already a handle, not a filename. But Daniel is right. You could process the contents without mapping it in a BytesIO object;

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre   Thank you! Yes, it works!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre   Please, put it like a answer!

Comment: I recommend the second approach which is less "bloated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're passing a `BytesIO` object (basically a file handle) where a filename is expected.

So quickfix:

```
f = BytesIO(response.content)
```

but better, iterate on a `bytes` objects using `iter` either manually (for the start of your algorithm) or automatically (using a `for` loop which will stop when the iterator is exhausted, so no need for `while`):

```
f = iter(response.content)

byte = next(f)

#some algorithm..............
for byte in f:
    hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(byte)
    decimal = int(hexadecimal, 16)
    binary = bin(decimal)[2:].zfill(8)
    hiddenData += binary
```